# Do not allow users save document library on the server and be able to save on the local

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions

I have a document library. Users can see and download it.

When users open the document and change it, they can save changes.

**Problem is:** when user click save, save file dialog show server path and user can save file on the server. user should not save file to server and save it only on the local.

Comment: Remove the access of users from server. How come they have access to server to locate the file.

Comment: I don't because user should  save file on the server in a special webpart :(

Comment: how you are using this webpart. This will be a big risk to have a user access to the server.

Comment: No, when user add item to a list. a document added to document library.

Comment: Does it show actual server path (c:\path\on\server\) or http(s)://hostname/path/to/library?